# Exception: must be reducible node in Entity Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm getting an exception in Entity Core 1.1.0 when I try to "concatenate" multiple IQueryable where clauses that use a Navigation Property.

Simple example (not my actual code):

```
 public List<ProjectSummaryDto> TestRelation(string s)
    {
            var query = _context.TechnologicallyProject
            .WhereIf(! string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s), q => q.Document.Title.Contains(s))
            .ProjectTo<ProjectSummaryDto>();

        return query.ToList();  //Exception Message: must be reducible node
    }
```

Stack trace:

> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceAndCheck() at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceExtensions() at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExtensionExpression(Expression
>   expr, Stack stack) ....

But When, Contains(Title) to Equlas(id) it changes, it works without problems

```
 public List<ProjectSummaryDto> TestRelation(int s)
    {

        var query = _context.TechnologicallyProject
            .WhereIf(s != 0 , q => q.Document.Id.Equals(s))
            .ProjectTo<ProjectSummaryDto>();

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: What are you passing as 's' in each case?

Answer (score 2):

- The last version of EF Core 1.1.x is `1.1.4` now (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/releases). Try to update your project first.
- Also this error is a bug and should be reported to the EF Team. more info: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/search?q=must+be+reducible+node&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93
- If you want to report it, try to post a re-producable sample, not just a part of it.